# Is this formula in predicate logic a tautology?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$\left(\forall x \cdot p(X) \Rightarrow q(X)\right) \wedge p(Y) \Rightarrow q(Y)$

At first glance this seems like a tautlogy and that's what my notes say. But an interpretation where $p$ is always true and $q$ is always false seems to be a counterexample.

Can someone confirm this or show me where I've gone wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you leave out a quantifier on $Y$? (Is Y a variable or a name?)

Comment: That's how my notes show it. I'm assuming Y is just a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a counterexample. In the case where $p$ is always true and $q$ is always false you have
$$(\forall X ,p(X) \Rightarrow q(X)) \qquad \mbox{ false}$$
$$(\forall X ,p(X) \Rightarrow q(X)) \wedge p(Y)\qquad \mbox{ false}$$
$$(\forall X ,p(X) \Rightarrow q(X)) \wedge p(Y) \Rightarrow q(Y)\qquad \mbox{ true}$$
since $\mbox{ false} \Rightarrow \mbox{ true}$ is true.

Comment: Ah yes. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is *valid*; after restoring the parentheses for better readibility, we have :

> $(∀x[p(x) \to q(x)] ∧ p(y)) \to q(y)$.

*Proof*

1) $∀x[p(x) \to q(x)] ∧ p(y)$ --- assumed

2) $∀x[p(x) \to q(x)]$ --- from 1) by b$\land$-elimination

3) $p(y)$ --- from 1) by b$\land$-elimination

4) $p(y) \to q(y)$ --- from 2) by $\forall$-elimination

5) $q(y)$ --- from 3) and 4) by $\to$-elimination

> 6) $(∀x[p(x) \to q(x)] ∧ p(y)) \to q(y)$ --- from 1) and 5) by $\to$-introduction.

Comment: By the order of precidence for logic, do we really need the parentheses for this to be the case?

Comment: @user3734896 No, it is not *needed*; but Mauro added it for clarity.

Comment: @user3734896 - I prefer to use parentheses because it is not so clear that $(∀x.p(x) ⇒ q(x))$ means : $∀x(p(x) ⇒ q(x))$ and **not** : $∀xp(x) ⇒ q(x)$ ...